# Change markup used for product options in 1.9.x

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

I'd like to overwrite the way this file works:

> app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php

I thought all I had to do was copy it to:

> app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php

That does not appear to be working. Is there another option available?  My goal is just to change the HTML that is used here.

Comment: Had you clear all cache after put your file in local folder?

Comment: caching is turned off, but I did go in and clear it anyway.

Comment: So it is working now?

Comment: @ChiragRajput no.

Comment: Would you be able to accomplish your desired edits by copying `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type` to a subtheme\fallback file?  i.e. `app/design/frontend/your/theme/template/catalog/product/view/options/type`

Answer (score 0):

In the linked code (below for posterity), the path

> global/blocks/catalog/rewrite/Product_View_Options_Select

should be

> global/blocks/catalog/rewrite/product_view_options_select

because the block class is specified using lowercase in layout XML files (eg. https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml#L228).

> /app/code/local/Lbb/Catalog/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<config>  
    <modules>  
        <Lbb_Catalog>  
            <version>0.1.0</version>  
        </Lbb_Catalog>  
    </modules>  
    <global>  
        <blocks>  
            <catalog>  
                <rewrite>  
                        <product_view_options_type_select>Lbb_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select</product_view_options_type_select>  
                </rewrite>  
            </catalog>  
        </blocks>  
    </global>  
</config>
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks